# Comparing images

Tags: images, search, automation, comparison, pictures

I'm making a website for a company, only the previous webmaster resized all the images and pasted a watermark on them in the bottom right corner. Now I've got this huge 64GB folder with photos in which I need to find the original versions of the images on the website. Obviously this would take me way too long, and it would be boring work.

Is there anything that can help me speed up this tedious task?

---

Oh and obviously the file names have changed, too.

Comment: Find one and assume the previous webmaster was systematic?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The photos come from different locations in that 64GB folder.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the sort of programs Google shows for "image dedup" - some of them look like they might help for this sort of task.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick http://www.youtube.com/results?hl=en&safe=off&biw=1280&bih=692&q=image+depup&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=w1 I don't see any programs here.

Comment: [I do](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=image+dedupe&l=1)

Comment: (Why the hell did google.com get replaced with youtube.com?!)
@RedGrittyBrick Depup != Depupe

Comment: When are the watermarks added? Maybe you can check for specific batch run times or you find pairs of pictures (original and watermarked copy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to do a task very similar to what you describe.  The software I ended up using is called [Image Comparer](http://www.bolidesoft.com/imagecomparer.html).  It compares the images "visually" and then lists the ones it thinks match so you can compare them side-by-side (the pic and the file details).  They have a free version so you can try it with no obligation.  The trial version does just about everything except let you work in batches (so still fully functional, just a bit more tedious to use).   I did find that sometimes it would suggest 2 completely different images as being 99% equal, but they are pretty easy to spot so it didn't turn out to be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it (though I'd first need to set up a virtual machine with Windows, it seems).

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you want to write a program to completely automate the process, and the confounding factor will be that even the upper-left corners of the images, which are not polluted by the watermarks, are not identical in the resaved images due to lossy image compression.

Write a program to load and calculate some simple metrics for the upper-left part of each image, which should be nearly identical in the original and watermarked images.  Average pixel value, or x,y location of the max or min values.  Pair the images by closest match.

Comment: I haven't done anything with image manipulation yet in any programming language. Also, some of the images have been cropped.